# Google test gives me "Missing '}' or object member name" error and i cant find why

Tags: php, schema, jsonschema, schema.org

I cant find why this structure doesnt work properly. I tried thousands of different possibilities and always gives the same error: Missing '}' or object member name. error

It could be because of the unicode `&quot;` elements? i did try many ways to fix it but i couldnt find the good one

Its created by a loop in php:

```
$item_elements = array();
$count = count($srcs);
for($i = 0;$i < $count; $i++){
    $pos = $i+1;
    $here = [
        '@type' => 'ListItem',
        'position' => $pos,
        'item' => array(
                'name' => $titles[$i],
                'description' => $desc[$i],
                'url' => $hrefs[$i],
                'image' => $srcs[$i]
            )];
    array_push($item_elements, $here);
}

$output = [
    '@context' => 'https://schema.org',
    '@type' => 'ItemList',
    "name" => 'example name',
    'itemListElement' => $item_elements
];
?>
<script type="application/ld+json">
  <?php echo json_encode($output, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); ?>
</script>
```

This is the looking in the website:

```
{
    "@context": "https://schema.org",
    "@type": "ItemList",
    "name": "example name",
    "itemListElement": [
        {
            "@type": "ListItem",
            "position": 1,
            "item": {
                "name": "Segment Rings",
                "description": "Our seamless and segment rings are sold in different styles. There are segment rings which include a loose section that is clicked in place after insertion into the piercing and there are hinged segment rings, of which the section is attached to the ring. Both versions give the appearance of a continuous ring when inserted. Those segment and hinged segment rings are sold in PVD-plated and anodized versions and the gauges vary from 16g (1.2mm) to 4g (5mm). The diameters range from 6mm to 16mm.",
                "url": "https://www.achadirect.com/en/wholesale-seamless-and-segment-rings/others",
                "image": "https://wholesalebodyjewellery.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/element-titanium-seamless-segment.jpg"
            }
        },
        {
            "@type": "ListItem",
            "position": 2,
            "item": {
                "name": "Titanium Labrets With Multi-Crystal Balls",
                "description": "Our ASTM F-136 titanium (Ti6Al4V ELI) titanium labrets have a flat back piece that sits flat against the skin and internally threaded balls. They are often used for upper and lower lip piercings, ear piercings and even as nose jewellery. These labrets are ideal for oral use as the back plate does not irritate gums or teeth. The piercing balls are internally threaded.",
                "url": "https://www.achadirect.com/en/wholesale-titanium-g23/labrets",
                "image": "https://wholesalebodyjewellery.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/element-titanium-g23-labrets-with-crystal-balls.jpg"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And when i see the the test page HTML it shows the following:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
{
    &quot;@context&quot;: &quot;https://schema.org&quot;,
    &quot;@type&quot;: &quot;ItemList&quot;,
    &quot;name&quot;: &quot;example name&quot;,
    &quot;itemListElement&quot;: [
        {
            &quot;@type&quot;: &quot;ListItem&quot;,
            &quot;position&quot;: 1,
            &quot;item&quot;: {
                &quot;name&quot;: &quot;Segment Rings&quot;,
                &quot;description&quot;: &quot;Our seamless and segment rings are sold in different styles. There are segment rings which include a loose section that is clicked in place after insertion into the piercing and there are hinged segment rings, of which the section is attached to the ring. Both versions give the appearance of a continuous ring when inserted. Those segment and hinged segment rings are sold in PVD-plated and anodized versions and the gauges vary from 16g (1.2mm) to 4g (5mm). The diameters range from 6mm to 16mm.&quot;,
                &quot;url&quot;: &quot;https://www.achadirect.com/en/wholesale-seamless-and-segment-rings/others&quot;,
                &quot;image&quot;: &quot;https://wholesalebodyjewellery.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/element-titanium-seamless-segment.jpg&quot;
            }
        },
        {
            &quot;@type&quot;: &quot;ListItem&quot;,
            &quot;position&quot;: 2,
            &quot;item&quot;: {
                &quot;name&quot;: &quot;Titanium Labrets With Multi-Crystal Balls&quot;,
                &quot;description&quot;: &quot;Our ASTM F-136 titanium (Ti6Al4V ELI) titanium labrets have a flat back piece that sits flat against the skin and internally threaded balls. They are often used for upper and lower lip piercings, ear piercings and even as nose jewellery. These labrets are ideal for oral use as the back plate does not irritate gums or teeth. The piercing balls are internally threaded.&quot;,
                &quot;url&quot;: &quot;https://www.achadirect.com/en/wholesale-titanium-g23/labrets&quot;,
                &quot;image&quot;: &quot;https://wholesalebodyjewellery.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/element-titanium-g23-labrets-with-crystal-balls.jpg&quot;
            }
        }
    ]
}
</body></html>
```

You can see here everything:
[image: Rich results test error]

Comment: Always show us the COMPLETE Error message, do not summarise please

Comment: Hello @RiggsFolly, i added an image with everything :)

Comment: Just grasping at straws here, because I don't know your context, but is your script supposed to be just returning json? If so, then the `<script type="application/ld+json">` and `</script>` could be breaking Google's parser

Comment: _"This is the looking in the website:"_ - copy&pasted into https://jsonlint.com, that says it is perfectly valid JSON. _"It could be because of the unicode &quot; elements?"_ - that appears to be just the tool showing your your input data again, but it _is_ not the input data, that is what you put on the left, and there are normal quotes in there.

Comment: @Stevish input data given to the tool in the screenshot doesn't appear to contain those tags though.

Comment: Or maybe that is the issue - does the tool perhaps _want_ the full HTML source code of the page? Or at least the relevant schema data section, but _including_ those script tags?

Comment: What are you using this data for? What is supposed to be reading it? the pretty json option would probably mess it up if it's supposed to be read by a machine

Comment: RRT does not read PHP; it reads conventional HTML (microdata) and JSON-LD. The proof is on the right panel. The left panel simply formats the code; but the "real" source has the escaped quotes.